# react native Modal opening from last object in array

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog, expo

I am creating a render method where it displays information from a state array, and I want it so that when a user touches a Card a Modal will open presenting the same information.

My code is as follows:

```
this.state = {
  fontLoaded: false,
  feed: [{
    username: ["Jeff", "Kyle", "David"],
    caption: ["Great", "Amazing", "Not so Good"],
    comments: ["Comment 1", "Comment 2", "No Comment"],
    photo:[Pic1,Pic2,Pic3],
  }]
}

state = {
    isModalVisible: false,
  };

  toggleModal = () => {
    this.setState({ isModalVisible: !this.state.isModalVisible });
  };

renderFeed = () => {
    return this.state.feed.map((card, index) => {
      return card.username.map((username, i) => {
        if(card.caption[i])
          return (
            <View>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.toggleModal} underlayColor="white">
            <Card
            key={`${i}_${index}`}
image={card.photo[i]}
containerStyle={{borderRadius:10, marginRight:1, marginLeft:1,}}>
<View
    style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}
  >
  <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <Avatar 
        size="small"
        rounded
        source={card.photo[i]}
  />
    </View>
    <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
 <Avatar
    rounded
    icon={{ name:'heart-multiple-outline', type:'material-community', color: '#ff4284'}}
      overlayContainerStyle={{marginLeft:5}}
        reverse
   size='small'/>
   <Avatar
        reverse
        rounded
  icon={{ name:'comment-processing-outline', type:'material-community' }}
  overlayContainerStyle={{backgroundColor: '#dbdbdb',marginLeft:5}}
   size='small'/>
    </View>
  </View>
    { this.state.fontLoaded == true ? (
      <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
<Text style={{fontFamily: 'MontserratB', color:'#bf00b9', marginTop:10}}>{username}</Text>
    <Text style={{fontFamily:'Montserrat', marginTop:10}}>{card.caption[i]}</Text>
  </View>
            ) : (<Text> Loading...</Text>)
      }
          <Text style={{marginTop:4, color:'#878787'}}>{card.comments[i]}</Text>
</Card>
</TouchableHighlight>
<Modal 
animationIn="zoomInDown" 
animationOut="zoomOutDown" 
animationInTiming={700}
          animationOutTiming={600}
          backdropTransitionInTiming={600}
          backdropTransitionOutTiming={600}
           isVisible={this.state.isModalVisible}>
            <Image source={card.photo[i]}
            style={{width: SCREEN_WIDTH - 20,
                    height: 300, justifyContent: 'center', alignSelf: 
                    'center' }}/>
                    <Card
containerStyle={{ width: SCREEN_WIDTH - 20, marginTop: 0,  justifyContent: 'center', alignSelf: 
                    'center' }}>
<View style={{ flexDirection:'row' }}>
      <Avatar 
        size="small"
        rounded
        source={card.photo[i]}
  />
  <View style={{ flex:2, flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'flex-end' }}>
    <Avatar
    rounded
    icon={{ name:'heart-multiple-outline', type:'material-community'}}
      overlayContainerStyle={{backgroundColor: '#ff4284',marginLeft:5}}
        reverse
   size='small'/>
   <Avatar
        reverse
        rounded
  icon={{ name:'comment-processing-outline', type:'material-community' }}
  overlayContainerStyle={{backgroundColor: '#dbdbdb',marginLeft:5}}
   size='small'/>
   </View>
   </View>
   <View style={{ flexDirection:'row' }}>
    <Text style={{fontFamily: 'MontserratB', color:'#bf00b9', marginTop:10}}>{username}</Text>
    <Text style={{fontFamily:'Montserrat', marginTop:10}}>{card.caption[i]}</Text>
  </View>
    <Text style={{marginTop:4, color:'#878787'}}>{card.comments[i]}</Text>
</Card>

            <Button style={{marginTop:0, borderBottomRightRadius: 20, borderBottomLeftRadius: 20, borderTopLeftRadius: 0, borderTopRightRadius: 0, width: SCREEN_WIDTH - 20, alignSelf: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}} title="Close" onPress={this.toggleModal} />
        </Modal>
        </View>
          );
        return <React.Fragment />;
      });
    })
}
```

everything works perfectly except that no matter which Card is touched a Modal is opened presenting the last objects in the array. So no matter which of the three cards are pressed, a Modal will always open with the information regarding David

Comment: First of all, why you need to render modal component for each card, you can have one modal in page and in toggle function put to  state  the current item that you need in modal.

Comment: @Oleg How can I do that?

Comment: In toggleModal  you can put current item to state and in modal get what you need. Modal component put once out of map function.

Comment: @Oleg I'm still a bit confused since I am new to RN. Can you please give me a little more detail? Is there more information I need to post from my code?

Comment: can you post your code with demo example  in expo snack?

Comment: @Oleg https://snack.expo.io/@sooper_fly/sooper-dynamite here is a URL to the snack. I haven't added the images in the snack-expo, everything else is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified snack  version of your sample:
https://snack.expo.io/H1yHPQQdr

Comment: I am getting a warning regarding my key props, however I thought I had that part covered. Is there anything from the code that you think may be causing this warning?

Comment: This only example based on your code however you can make many improvements in  your project and refactoring but it is not scope of the current question.